# Is the Starcraft 2 Collector's Edition Ultralisk skin the same as the Leviathan skin?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm considering purchasing some skins for my StarCraft 2 account.

I will likely go for one of the packs to get a full set for ~$20, but I noticed that I could get the digital edition for about the same price, which would give me an Ultralisk skin (among all the other goodies) for about the same price.

Is the Leviathan skin and the Special Edition skin essentially the same thing for the Ultralisk?

I think the Leviathan might have slightly longer spines, but is that the only difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're somewhat similar (both purpleish in color), but it looks like they are different.

The Collector's Edition Ultralisk:

[image: The Collector's Edition Ultralisk]

The Leviathan Brood Ultralisk:

[image: The Leviathan Brood Ultralisk]

The Collector's Edition (CE) Ultralisk has a purple viscous looking substance on the bottom of its claws, while the Leviathan Brood (LB) Ultralisk has a row of spines sticking out of the bottom of its claws. The LB-Ultra has more prominent horns above its head and sticking out of each of its legs. The LB-Ultra also has larger spikes across its back and has rows of spines throughout, compared to the CE-Ultra. The LB-Ultra also seems to be more purple, while the CE-Ultra is more pink in color.

IMO, the Simulant skin for the Ultras is the best looking and most distinct one, but I also used to main Protoss. :D